# Django: run queries depending on SQL engine

Tags: sql, django, django-models

In Django 1.2.3 I need to perform some queries that are not feasible with pure Django ORM functions. E.g.

```
result = MyModel.objects.extra(select={'stddev': 'STDDEV_SAMP(value)'}).values()
```

But, indeed, I need to run this code on several SQL engines (sqllite, MySQL and MSSQL). So, I should test `settings.DATABASES['default']['engine']` and run engine-specific code.

Is there a more Django-like approach to this problem? (e.g. user-definined function to put somewhere so that Django run them according to default database engine).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper place to store the code for accessing data is in a method in the model layer.  That way, the model can:

- be environment-aware
- construct custom queries
- use built-in ORM functions

These can be swapped around, optimized, and tweaked, without the rest of your application having to change a bit, because the rest of your application only manipulates data through your model.

Comment: Agreed. Throw away UDF in the database, and replace them with functions on your model.

Comment: That code is already into a method (that gives the standard deviation od its instances values). What I am looking for is top contruct something like Django aggregation functions `Sum` or `Avg`, which are database-independent.

Comment: I think it's fine to check `settings.DATABASES['default']['engine']`.  You want to run different queries in different environments, but the interface to the data will remain the same.  It's fine to have somewhat messy stuff in the implementation, and I can't think of another way to run different code in different environments (other than checking the environment and reacting accordingly).